# Play2 Template Can't Populate Textarea

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'm creating a textarea in my form. Obviously I want to auto-populate it if any error occurs. So I did this:

```
<textarea name="content">@form("content")</textarea>
```

Then I find my textarea's space has `Form.Field(content)` written in. Is there a way to hide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are passing an instance of your form to your template, use `@helper.textarea(YOUR_FORM_INSTANCE("content"))` to fetch any existing value.

See [Scala Form Helpers (Play docs)](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaFormHelpers) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for help, but the default helper has many additional (unwanted) fields/labels..do you know how to remove them?

Comment: I don't understand; what do you mean by "additional fields/labels"?

Comment: sorry..the form helper will generate not only the <textarea>, but also with additional field like <dt><label></label></dt> <dd class="error">No Error</dd> and such..and I want none of these, but <textarea>

Comment: I see.  In that case you have to define your own "field constructor". Check "Writing your own field constructor" section in [Scala Form Helpers](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaFormHelpers).

Comment: Thank you! I find my needs mostly satisfied by passing in arguments into the field constructor (like "_showConstraints -> false"). I don't want to go all the way to create my own field template..but I really want to turn off the auto-generation of label..can I pass in an argument and simply achieve that?

Comment: As far as I know, no.

Comment: @JeremyGoodell Makes sense --been a while since I last worked with Play so can't try this.